# Why is there no other successful status codes in fastify route?

Tags: node.js, fastify

So I created a fastify route using `fastify.route`. But there is no way I could return a `201` statusCode in the response. And even if I return a 201 statusCode, it will be converted to a 200 one.

```
fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  schema: {
    querystring: {
      name: { type: 'string' },
      excitement: { type: 'integer' }
    },
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          hello: { type: 'string' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
  }
})
```

¶

### **EDIT**

The code that I was referring to was that of swagger

```
response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          hello: { type: 'string' }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here I want to replace 200 with a 201, and gives the required fields, but seems like that is not throwing an error as imagined

This is messing up my post request.

Comment: Where are you returning a 201? Please show the code.

Comment: by the way, you should call `reply.code(201)`

Comment: I was specifically mentioning about the swagger code of 200

Comment: I have added more context to the problem

Comment: Do you think that setting the status code, in the `response` schema, the reply should update accordingly?

Comment: No, but the schema plays a role when it comes to `required` fields, and the `required` field is only getting validated when the schema resposne code is 200, I am not seeing 201 code, what if we want to let know the front end devs that the response code 201?